# How can I handle this "which is not a subtype of overridden" error

Tags: generics, kotlin, generic-variance, type-projection

I'm trying to write some validatable form interface in Kotlin. In the validation part I'm using https://github.com/kamedon/Validation.

Here is the very simple code I'm trying to run;

```
import com.kamedon.validation.Validation


abstract class Validatable {
    abstract val validation: Validation<Any>

    fun validate() = validation.validate(this)
}

class LoginForm : Validatable() {
    val name: String = "Onur"
    val age: Int = 23

    override val validation = Validation<LoginForm> {
        "name" {
            be { name.length >= 5 } not "5 characters or more"
            be { name.length <= 10 } not "10 characters or less"
        }
        "age" {
            be { age >= 20 } not "Over 20 years old"
        }
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = LoginForm()
    val result = user.validate()
    println(result)
}
```

This code gives me;

```
Type of 'validation' is not a subtype of the overridden property 'public abstract val validation: Validation<Any> defined in Validatable'
```

If I use `Validation<out Any>` in Validatable it says;

```
Kotlin: Out-projected type 'Validation<out Any>' prohibits the use of 'public final fun validate(value: T): Map<String, List<String>> defined in com.kamedon.validation.Validation'
```

If I use `Validation<in Any>` in Validatable it says;

```
Kotlin: Type of 'validation' is not a subtype of the overridden property 'public abstract val validation: Validation<in Any> defined in Validatable'
```

If I use `Validation<Any>` instead of `Validation<LoginForm>` in LoginForm, the code runs but this time name and age inside of `validation` are used from the class inside itself. I don't want to change this in respect of the usage of the library.

Is there anyway to use `in` and `out` keywords together or may be there is another way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the abstract class `Validatable` a generic class, and make the subclass provide an object which exposes both the `Validation` object, and also itself as the `target` to validate, e.g.

```
abstract class Validatable<T> {
    protected class ValidationInfo<T>(val target: T, val validation: Validation<T>)

    protected abstract val validationInfo: ValidationInfo<T>

    fun validate() = validationInfo.let { it.validation.validate(it.target) }
}

class LoginForm : Validatable<LoginForm>() {
    val name: String = "Onur"
    val age: Int = 23

    override val validationInfo = ValidationInfo(this, Validation {
        "name" {
            be { name.length >= 5 } not "5 characters or more"
            be { name.length <= 10 } not "10 characters or less"
        }
        "age" {
            be { age >= 20 } not "Over 20 years old"
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried this but this time validation.validate(this) doesn't work. it requires `this` as `T` but receives `Validatable<T>`. Compiler complains for this.

Comment: Yup, you're right, my mistake. I've updated my answer with a slightly different approach, though I think there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Very clever solution. Thank you.